# Code returns the same thing after compilation?

Tags: c++

I'm having some serious issues with my code right now. The assignment is to write a function(s) that accepts a 4 digit integer, encrypts it and returns the newly encrypted number.

For some reason, my code returns the exact same thing(the number 1886676324) after I compile it. It doesn't even read the cout statement. Can someone please take a look and see what's wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int numSwap(int A[])
{
int t;
int encryptedVal= 0;
for(int i =0; i<4; i++)
{
if((i == 0)|(i == 1)){
A[i+2] = t;
A[i+2] = A[i];
A[i] = t;
}
encryptedVal = (A[i] * 10^(3-i)) + encryptedVal;
}
return encryptedVal;
}

int encrypt(int N)
{
int A[4];
for(int i =0; i<4; i++)
{
div_t M = div(N,(10^(3-i)));
div_t Encrypted = div(7+M.quot,10);
A[i] = Encrypted.rem;
N= M.rem;
}
return numSwap(A);
}

int main()
{
int UserVal;
cout<< 'Please input the 4 digit value to be encrypted' <<endl;
cin>>UserVal;
encrypt(UserVal);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive.  You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, and then construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).

Comment: `^` is not for raising to the power. It does bitwise exclusive OR.

Comment: "It doesn't even read the cout statement." - what does that suppose to mean?

Comment: I mean the only thing that comes up on command prompt is the number 1886676324. it doesn't get to the cout statement(lol sorry maybe that was worded improperly)

Comment: `Can someone please take a look and see what's wrong?` Nope.

Answer (score 3):

To fix your problem with the `cout`, make sure you use double quotes for string literals:

```
cout << "Please input the 4 digit value to be encrypted" << endl;
```

Single quotes are for character literals (like `'a'` or `'b'`) which are of type `char`. If you give more than one character in a character literal, you have a *multicharacter literal* which is of type `int` with implementation-defined value, hence the number you got as output.

Comment: Hey thanks bro. Turns out the single quotes was the main issue

Comment: @Jonathan If I may say so, 'bro', I think the main issue was that you didn't read your C++ book carefully :)